# How to change query into fetch result in coredata(magical record)?

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord, nsfetchedresultscontroller, predict

i want fetch request for below query

```
select name,count(1) from tablename groupedby name;
```

i tried to add grouped by fetch controller not succeed
how to do that

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't have group by query in MR without FRC. So may be you need something like:

`+ (NSFetchedResultsController *) MR_fetchAllSortedBy:(NSString *)sortTerm ascending:(BOOL)ascending withPredicate:(NSPredicate *)searchTerm groupBy:(NSString *)groupingKeyPath delegate:(id<NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>)delegate;`;

If you still need just query, you can take a look a this [solution](http://mattconnolly.wordpress.com/2012/06/21/ios-core-data-group-by-and-count-results/)